# Интервал проверки новых заказов в базе, WebSocket

Tags: php, mysql, websocket

Есть WS сервер, написан на Ratchet.

Продумываю реализацию такой задачи:

Есть 2 типа пользователей, реализатор(Р) и покупатель(П).

У всех при коннекте к сайту - устанавливается WS соединение.

Реализатор выложил товар на сайте, и сидит на одной странице, без каких либо действий, с активным подключением по WS.

И вот покупатель, покупает товар - и в этот момент необходимо реализатору дать оповещение о том, что его товар купили.

Как здесь лучше реализовать?..

У меня вариант такой:
На сервере где веб-сокет приложение, делать периодически запросы в базу, на проверку новых записей в таблице продаж, и выводить пользователю информацию. Но я не думаю что это лучший вариант, так как база будет нагружена постоянными такими запросами...

Как лучше сделать, и минимизировать нагрузку на базу?

Comment: Сам я, честно, не разбирался в этом, но знаю, что в ратчете есть подписки - это когда можно подключить группу пользователей (реализаторы в твоём случае) к отдельному каналу и отправлять им функции с каким-нибудь событием (покупка товара) http://socketo.me/docs/wamp

Comment: Хотя можно и просто отправлять сообщение на сокет от покупателя после покупки с указанием id реализатора и затем отправлять по указанному в сообщении id оповещение.

Comment: @Diskyp хотя да, при покупке можно вызывать функцию оповещения о покупке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аккумулировать на сервере информацию для обмена данными в реальном времени, а в базу заносить текущий информационный буфер сервера - централизовано и с определённой периодичностью.